# Jquery Mobile Popup Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, popup

i have some popups in my app. but i cant understand when i click on the button to open and to close he has a big delay on my ipad.

Is it possible to set it faster?

```
<div data-role="popup" id="positionWindow">
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
  some text
</div>

<a href="#positionWindow" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="Window" data-inline="true">
  <img src="images/plus.png"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)?

Answer (score 0):

How big is the image?, check the size and if it can be reduced to save rendering time